# Factorygirl error using callback: Wrong Number of Arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, tdd, factory-bot

Hello and thanks for reading. Here's my factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :venue do
    sequence(:name) { |n| "ExampleVenue#{n}" }

    factory :venue_with_gig do
      after_create do |venue|
        create(:gig, venue: venue)               #I've created a valid gig factory as well
      end                                        
    end
  end
end
```

A venue has_many gigs and gigs belong_to venues. What I have here seems like it follows the examples on the thoughtbot [blog post here](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/254496652/aint-no-calla-back-girl)

Yet, I run my model specs and get failures due to the error `wrong Number of Arguments (3 for 2) at the`before` action below:

require 'spec_helper'

```
describe Venue do
  describe "basic attributes" do
    before { @venue = create(:venue_with_gig) }

    subject { @venue }

    it { should be_valid }
    it { should respond_to(:name) }
    # it { should respond_to(:address) }
    it { should respond_to(:gigs) }
  end 

  describe "with invalid params" do
    before { @venue = build(:venue, name: " ") }
    subject { @venue }

    it { should_not be_valid }
  end
end
```

I've looked at it for too long and can use a fresh perspective. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since venue has may gigs, it's necessary to define how man gigs you need when saying "venue_with_gig", for which a better name is "venue_with_gigs". Also you need to use `create_list`

```
# under venue define as your code
factory :venue_with_gigs do
  ignore do
    gigs_count 3 # Let's say 3 gigs as default
  end

  after(:create) do |venue, evaluator|
    FactoryGirl.create_list(:gig, evaluator.gigs_count, venue: venue)
  end                                        
end
```

Use it with default

```
FactoryGirl.create(:venue_with_gigs)
# => 1 venue and 3 gigs created. Gigs under the venue
```

Custom quantity

```
FactoryGirl.create(:venue_with_gigs, gigs_count: 10)
# => 1 venue 10 gigs created
```

Comment: I need to research this a bit more. I just had time to run the code as-is and got a `undefined method `gigs_count' for #<FactoryGirl::Declaration::Implicit:0x007f90e7d6c700>`. When I have time later I'll research FactoryGirl docs and see if there is some slight error here or if something is omitted. I will say that considering what I linked above, this seems excessive, though of course I'm not ruling out the possibility that your suggestion will solve my problem. Thanks!

Comment: I deleted my comment because my edit was rejected. I've also unchecked this as the answer because now the code is broken. The biggest thing is passing in `evaluator` as an argument in between the pipes in the `after(:create)` block. Once you make the edit, I'll go ahead and accept the answer again.

Comment: @aceofbassgreg, yes it should be `after(:create)` instead of `after_create`. In first version I just copied your code blindly :)

Comment: Also you still need to add `evaluator` to the `after(:create)` block :-). The code should read: `after(:create) do |venue, evaluator|`. Sorry! Since I can't edit my only other option is answering my own question, which doesn't seem fair since you got me in this direction.